# CS0246: The type or namespace 'IQue' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am receiving a very weird error on one of my simply controller actions in Asp.net MVC. If I try to simply load the page, I receive this error:

```
CS0246: The type or namespace 'IQue' could not be found.
Line 29:     
Line 30:     
Line 31:     public class   _Page_Views_Unit_InventoryLocationsList_cshtml :      System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IQue> {
Line 32:         
Line 33: #line hidden
```

My code for the controller and view are a simple viewmodel based actionresult method. I can post them if need be.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have demolished one of your views. Simply open up the relevant view and put back the rest after `@model IQue`, which should be something like `@model IQueryable<InventoryLocation>`. Check your source control for the history of the file, or if you don't have that, go do that first and then check in your controller which model type you're passing to the view. We can't know what's supposed to be there. :)

Comment: Wow. Thats crazy. Thanks man.